# Importing goals from Analytics into AdWords and changing goal criteria in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-ads-api

When importing goals from Analytics into AdWords and then making changes to the goal criteria in Analytics, is it possible to "re-import" goals to AdWords with the changes or will it pick them up automatically?

Answer (score 2):

When changing goals value it will be counted by Google Analytics from date when criteria is changed, It is not possible to change goals backwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer to this yet, it has to be manually achieved.  Each Conversion that was imported into Adwords - has to be manually renamed to match the new value in Analytics.  You cannot currently re-import Analytics Goals.